# How to make angularJS controller be active at all times?

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am developing an angularJS application where my geocordinates from the device are taken and sent to my REST service every few seconds. Code for geo coordinates sending is located in just one controller. It means that geolocation is only updated in my server if the template page for that controller is open. How do I make it so that geolocation  is always updated regardless of which page I am on.

Here is my code for that controller:

```
.controller('geolocationCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', 'geolocationFactory',
        function($scope, $http, geolocationFactory) {

            // constants should be uppercase
            var GET_PATH = 'https://temp-domain.co.uk/rest/rest.php/client/geolocation',
                PUT_PATH = 'https://temp-domain.co.uk/rest/rest.php/client/geolocation/update';


            $http.get(GET_PATH).then(function (response) {
                var respLong = Number(response.data.longitude),
                    respLat = Number(response.data.latitude);

                $scope.map = drawMap(respLong, respLat);
                $scope.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(respLong, respLat)
                });
                $scope.marker.setMap($scope.map);

            }, function (errorResponse) {
                console.error('error response ' + errorResponse);
            });

            function drawMap(latitude, longitude) {
                var lat = latitude,
                    long = longitude,
                    currentLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: currentLatlng,
                    zoom: 10
                });
                return map;
            };

            setInterval(function () {
                geolocationFactory.getCurrentPosition().then(function(location) {

                    var newLatitude = location.coords.latitude,
                        newLongitude = location.coords.longitude;

                    // delete old marker
                    $scope.marker.setMap(null);
                    $scope.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: {
                            lat: newLatitude,
                            lng: newLongitude
                        }
                    });
                    var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newLatitude, newLongitude);
                    $scope.map.setCenter(LatLng);
                    $scope.marker.setMap($scope.map);


                    // send data to server
                    $http.put(PUT_PATH, {
                        "longitude": newLatitude,
                        "latitude": newLongitude
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        console.log('data sended');
                    }, function (errorResponse) {
                        console.error(errorResponse);
                    });
                }.bind(this));

            }, 2000);

        }])
```

This is my service.js

```
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('BlankFactory', [function(){

}])

.service('BlankService', [function(){

}])
.factory('geolocationFactory', ['$window', '$rootScope', '$q', function ($window, $rootScope, $q) {

    function supported() {
        return 'geolocation' in $window.navigator;
    }

    var retVal = {
        getCurrentPosition: function (options) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (supported()) {
                $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    function (position) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            this.coords = position.coords;
                            this.timestamp = position.timestamp;
                            deferred.resolve(position);
                        });
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            deferred.reject({error: error});
                        });
                    }, options);
            } else {
                deferred.reject({
                    error: {
                        code: 2,
                        message: 'This web browser does not support HTML5 Geolocation'
                    }
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        drawMarker: function (lat, lng) {

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                title: "Hello World!"
            });
        }
    };
    return retVal;
}]);
```

Comment: Put that code is a service, not in a controller.

Comment: i have updated my code, can you please show me how should i modify my code?

Answer (score 0):

Move the interval query into the service.  When there is a change, fire an event that the controller listens for to update its scope.

Modified service:

```
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('BlankFactory', [function(){

}])

.service('BlankService', [function(){

}])
.factory('geolocationFactory', ['$window', '$rootScope', '$q', '$interval', '$http', function ($window, $rootScope, $q, $interval, $http) {

    function supported() {
        return 'geolocation' in $window.navigator;
    }

    var retVal = {
        getCurrentPosition: function (options) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (supported()) {
                $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    function (position) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            this.coords = position.coords;
                            this.timestamp = position.timestamp;
                            deferred.resolve(position);
                        });
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            deferred.reject({error: error});
                        });
                    }, options);
            } else {
                deferred.reject({
                    error: {
                        code: 2,
                        message: 'This web browser does not support HTML5 Geolocation'
                    }
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        drawMarker: function (lat, lng) {

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                title: "Hello World!"
            });
        }
    };


    // the factory service runs at startup, so the interval will run the whole time the app is running
    $interval(function () {
        retVal.getCurrentPosition().then(function(location) {

            var newLatitude = location.coords.latitude,
                newLongitude = location.coords.longitude;

            // broadcast event
            $rootScope.$broadcast('geolocationCurrentPosition', newLatitude, newLongitude);

            // send data to server
            $http.put(PUT_PATH, {
                "longitude": newLatitude,
                "latitude": newLongitude
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log('data sended');
            }, function (errorResponse) {
                console.error(errorResponse);
            });
        }.bind(this));

    }, 2000);

    return retVal;
}]);
```

Modified controller:

```
.controller('geolocationCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {

        // constants should be uppercase
        var GET_PATH = 'https://temp-domain.co.uk/rest/rest.php/client/geolocation',
            PUT_PATH = 'https://temp-domain.co.uk/rest/rest.php/client/geolocation/update';


        $http.get(GET_PATH).then(function (response) {
            var respLong = Number(response.data.longitude),
                respLat = Number(response.data.latitude);

            $scope.map = drawMap(respLong, respLat);
            $scope.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(respLong, respLat)
            });
            $scope.marker.setMap($scope.map);

        }, function (errorResponse) {
            console.error('error response ' + errorResponse);
        });

        function drawMap(latitude, longitude) {
            var lat = latitude,
                long = longitude,
                currentLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: currentLatlng,
                zoom: 10
            });
            return map;
        };

        // listen for the event from geolocationFactory
        $scope.$on('geolocationCurrentPosition', function(event, latitude, longitude){
            // delete old marker
            $scope.marker.setMap(null);
            $scope.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {
                    lat: latitude,
                    lng: longitude
                }
            });
            var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            $scope.map.setCenter(LatLng);
            $scope.marker.setMap($scope.map);
        });
    }])
```